# Can I use alt-codes in Windows 7 on a Macbook pro?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook-pro

Is it possible to use alt codes for special characters on a Macbook Pro running Windows? I've tried <kbd>alt</kbd> and the numbers, I've tried <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>, I've tried guessing where a <kbd>fn</kbd> keypad might lay (<kbd>7</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>m</kbd>) but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my question phrased poorly or inappropriate for this site?

Answer (score 2):

A keyboard remapping tool should work for you, such as SharpKeys: [Basic description](https://www.randyrants.com/category/sharpkeys/) / [current release](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases).

*(Updated by yms and other(s) after the initial answer to provide an answer that should be more reassuring.)*

Comment: Not going to lie, that looks pretty shady. I'm not going to download that exe.